# Limit question where $f(x)=\sin x$ using the definition of the derivative

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)=\sin x$, I am asked to evaluate the following limit to two decimal places:

$$\lim _{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac {f\left( 2+h\right) -f\left( 2\right) } {h}$$

So far I have the following using an identity:

$$\lim _{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac {\sin \left( 2\right) \cos \left( h\right) +\cos \left( 2\right) \sin \left( h\right) -\sin \left( 2\right) } {h}$$

Using a hint, I am still stuck:

$$\lim _{h\rightarrow 0}\left( \dfrac {\sin \left( 2\right) \left( \cos \left( h\right) -1\right) +\cos \left( 2\right) \sin \left( h\right) } {h}\right) $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1 $$

$$ \lim_{x \to 0 } \frac{\cos x- 1}{x} = 0 $$

Added:

Now, put

$$ \phi(h) = \dfrac {\sin \left( 2\right) \cos \left( h\right) +\cos \left( 2\right) \sin \left( h\right) -\sin \left( 2\right) } {h} $$

You want $\lim_{h \to 0} \phi(h) $. Notice,

$$ \phi(h) = \frac{ \sin(2) \cos(h) - \sin(2) + \cos(2)\sin(h)}{h} = \frac{ \sin(2) (\cos(h)-1)}{h} + \frac{ \cos (2) \sin (h)}{h}$$

Hence,

$$ \lim_{h\to0} \phi(h) = \sin(2) \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\cos(h)-1}{h} + \cos(2) \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sin(h)}{h} = \sin(2) \cdot 0 + \cos(2) \cdot 1 = \cos(2) $$

Comment: Okay so I simplified but I still end up with $\lim _{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac {\cos \left( 2\right) } {h}$

Comment: I have edited my answer. See the last line. I hope it helps.

Comment: Oh.. Forgot you can factor out. Thanks for the response!